# Reading or writing a file in /data on a rooted Android device

Tags: android, root

I am trying to programmatically read/write a file in /data directory on a rooted phone.
I first *shell execute* **su** to make sure my program gets super user access, which works fine.

I am able to read/write files in /data thru shell *execs* commands inside my program, but I am getting "**Permission denied**" java.io.IOException when using Android File or other APIs.

How to use the APIs to read/write to /data on a rooted phone ? this is obviously possible as programs such as Root Explorer does it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

In short, no, this is not **strictly** possible through the API's as you need to make sure that your modification commands as run as root, or else the OS will reject those operations.

You need to pipe the modification commands to the `su` command in order for it to execute as root. 
On his [github](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/tree/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser), Chainfire provides a [sample implementation](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/blob/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser/Shell.java) of a `Shell` class that you can use to execute `rm` commands, or any other command, as root.

One way that you could do it programmatically would be do copy the file you are trying to edit to a temporary directory, say `/sdcard/tmp.txt`, and edit that file, then copy it back to the original location and overwrite the one there.

Another way would be to `chmod` the target file (ie `chmod 777 /data/xxx.txt`) so that you can read/write its contents programmatically. That is why you are getting the `Permission denied` error because your program does not have permission to access to other files. The key here is that you need to make sure that the `chmod` command itself is piped into the `su` command so that THAT command does not get denied. I would suggest reading the guide in the link below as it is very thorough in how you can approach situations where running as root is necessary.

Source: [How-To SU](http://su.chainfire.eu/#how)

Comment: Does not answer the question asked, which was to access the file rather change change its permissions.

Comment: Still not a very good answer.  And please take time to learn what the individual permission bits do instead of recommended slapping 777 on things.

Comment: There is high risk of setting file permission to 777.Because after setting the permission to 777 means this will make the file readable and writable for all other application or processes.So until your application sets it back to default permission,your file is under huge risk(if it is a confidential file).Also other problem is after your app sets permission to 777 and crashes(may be of other problems) without reverting back to original permissions will be huge risk forever.Because it is simply readable and writable all over the world.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your comment but I'll address the most obvious one: if the application is already modifying that file then that means that the phone is rooted, meaning that any data that is stored on the device in an unencrypted state is vulnerable to inspection by any application anyway. Giving full access to that file is hardly the least of an application developer's worries on a rooted device given that the device is insecure by nature at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Through coding you can add up a line like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 077" +your_file_you_need_to_give_permission);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would partially solve the problem, as I would prefer to directly get the permissions without chmod'ing the file, I would just like to have my program benefit the root access (given by shell executing su) to read/write files in /data without any other shell exec.

Comment: @JS_ : Can you pls elaborate? I didn't get you.

Comment: The goal here is to have the program benefit from the root access and have the APIs natively use the read/write access to data. The solution you offered may work, but relies on additional shell execs, which are probably not the best solution. Ideally it should work thru regular APIs as Root Explorer or other programs seems to use.

Comment: There is no other APIs, Root Explorer and other apps use shell commands with su.

Comment: There is high risk of setting file permission to 777.Because after setting the permission to 777 means this will make the file readable and writable for all other application or processes.So until your application sets it back to default permission,your file is under huge risk(if it is a confidential file).Also other problem is after your app sets permission to 777 and crashes(may be of other problems) without reverting back to original permissions will be huge risk forever.Because it is simply readable and writable all over the world.